# Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a windows application containing certain unit tests, whenever i try to run or debug any unit test i get the below error in test explorer-

Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..

I'm using Visual studio 2012 premium with the latest update and Code coverage is not enabled.
Any help in resolving the issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research i found the solution. 
I shared my solution folder to everyone, removing the sharing executed my unit tests. But this again brought another issue of symbol loading taking lots of time to load. I earlier had enabled Fusion log in my machine disabling it made my unit tests take less time to load the symbols.
Complicated, but happy that i found the answer..

Comment: I have this problem now. Do you mean the folder in Windows Explorer? Can you give  detailed steps on what you did?